# Fuzzing of Mobile Applications

Tags: android, mobile, ios, fuzzing

I have used [AFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_fuzzy_lop_(fuzzer)) recently for fuzzing of OpenSSL and it worked great. Now I am interesting in fuzzing mobile applications like I have got some `.apk` and `.ipa` files which I need to fuzz.

I searched on internet and found out about `afl-android`, `ios-afl` etc. However they only have a small community I guess (I might be wrong here) as I wasn't able to find a lot of documentation or blogs for their usage.

Are there anyother Mobile Application fuzzers which work on blackbox mechanism, like `.apk`-files?

Comment: can someone please provide answer to this question since I am need to start this project. Thanks.